# Timesat 3.3 TSM_GUI "Error while evaluating Menu Callback" on Sentinel2 NDVI time series

Tags: ndvi, sentinel-2, timesat

I try using timesat on a 1 year NDVI time series (gapfilled) from Sentinel 2 imagery but I have an error message (see screenshot).
I converted each .tif NDVI image into flat binary format using the following command on a shell OSGeo4W:
for %N in (*.tif) DO gdal_translate -of ENVI %N Convert%~nN.img

Then I created the list of image and checked the number of image in the list.
When using the "show image" button on the "images_file_input" window, the NDVI images are correctly mapped.

But then, the error message occurs.

Does anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it doesn't work because I only have a one year NDVI time series. A solution can be found by duplicating the time series (or downloading a 2 year time series).